# Android Sq lite DB text localization

Tags: android, sqlite, localization

Sq lite database file in my android application with some pre-loaded data. I know its easy to convert specific locale by using Values-Us-en etc.. . In my case i need to support only two languages English and Japanese. So if i am selecting language as Japanese from my application then the data loaded from db will show in Japanese language . Is there any method available for doing the same. I tried with making the copy of same table with Japanese data, but i  think it's not a good and reliable solution. Kindly give me solution if its possible. I don't know whether its possible or not.